# How do I download/copy 15,000 folders from an FTP server to local machine on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp

I want to download around 15,000 folders not files from an FTP server to my remote drive. I have FTP software but it’s time consuming to do a batch transfer with it.

So I am looking for a command line procedure (Windows) to get the folders from the server to local drive. If I get the correct command line (Windows) I can build the batch file and run it during off hours.

Comment: Is it a website host you're copying files from? Do they have CPanel? If they do, use the web file manager from CPanel to create a ZIP archive of the root folder containing the 15000 sub folders and download the archive file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

- Use ftp.exe from the command line (or batch file). There is a list of commands for Microsofts FTP tool on [nsftools.com](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) though I noticed some differences between it and what I see on Windows 8.1, so it would be best to run `ftp /?` to get the proper help info for you.
- If you're feeling adventurous, you could look into using the FTPWebRequest .Net class in PowerShell (example over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936108/how-to-script-ftp-upload-and-download).)
- Have a look at the [PowerShell FTP Client Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb), which I assume is a nice wrapper for the previously mentioned .Net class. I haven't used this myself.
- Check to see if you can increase the simultaneous streams/downloads within the GUI application you've used. This may be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) from a batch file:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@host/" ^
    "get /root/* c:\archive\" ^
    "exit"
```

It will download all files and subfolders from remote `/root/` folder recursively.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to give a look to [Wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or, if the remote server will allow you, even to [rsync for windows](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) or [the rsync windows backup agent](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howt/windows_backup_agent.html).

Some notes on **Wget:**

> **GNU Wget** is a free network utility to retrieve files from the World Wide Web using HTTP and FTP, the two most widely used Internet protocols. It works non-interactively, thus enabling work in the background, after having logged off.
>
> The recursive retrieval of HTML pages, as well as FTP sites is supported...
> ...Wget works exceedingly well on slow or unstable connections, keeping getting the document until it is fully retrieved. Re-getting files from where it left off works on servers (both HTTP and FTP) that support it

Some other about **The rsync Tool In Windows:**

> **rsync** synchronizes your local and offsite filesystems by transferring only the changed portions of files. After your initial upload, each subsequent upload will be very fast, as only the differences in the files are sent.
>
> **Windows Backup Agent**: rsync.net customers have access to a powerful, easy to use backup agent that handles automated, encrypted backups - even open files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use windows explorer and use your mouse.

[image]